# Index for SubTotal Rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql

i am trying to achieve the following thing on Sql, which is order the query by a creating a random column (like index) in query, it sounds simple but i cant figure out how to give each row the position i want, gona show my problem.

What i acomplish so far was something like this:

I did this by doing a subquery and union between then, but now i want to create a column (like a index) to order my table like i want but i dont know how to do it if someane can help would apreciate:

How to create a index column and give to each row of that column the value you want for at the end you order by like you you want?

Jonathan

```
    Bananas 10
     Orange  6
     Potato  2
```

Joana

```
     Bananas 3
     Orange  1
     Juice   3
```

Mark

```
     Potato  5
     Peanuts 7
```

Luigi

```
     Potato  10
     Orange  10
```

SubTotal        12

SubTotal        18

SubTotal        20

SubTotal        7

...

 ...

**OutPutDesired**  
 **ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC** 


**Jonathan** 

   Bananas             10    

           Orange              6    

            Potato      2            

    **SubTotal**     18

Joana   Orange  1

    Juice   3

    **SubTotal** 4

Mark  

    Peanuts 5

    Potato  7

    **SubTotal** 12

 **Luigi** 

    Potato  10

    Orange  10

    **SubTotal** 20

"

[Input/OutPut/IdeaToAchieveOutput](https://prntscr.com/ncfyct)

Comment: Can you create an output in Excel or such, take a screenshot and post it? Also, can you take a screenshot of how your data looks in postgres?

Comment: Hi @zedfoxus http://prntscr.com/ncfyct

Comment: In that print that is everything. from how it looks like actualy and how output should look like, basicaly is too add index column and give your own values to the rows you want for later when your order by you can make it work. (just dont know i can i create index column and give the values to the rows i want :(

Comment: What does your question have to do with your sample data.  I'm lost.  Where is the random column?

Comment: @mrluffy I see that your question is still open. You have the option of keeping your question open to solicit additional answers or you can give it closure by marking an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in this manner:

**Table**

```
create table ex1 (
  person text,
  food text,
  amount int
);
```

**Data**

```
insert into ex1 values
('Jonathan', 'Bananas', 10),
('Jonathan', 'Orange', 6),
('Jonathan', 'Potato', 2),
('Joana', 'Bananas', 3),
('Joana', 'Orange', 1),
('Joana', 'Juice', 3),
('Mark', 'Potato', 5),
('Mark', 'Peanuts', 7),
('Luigi', 'Potato', 10),
('Luigi', 'Orange', 10);
```

**Query**

```
with subtotals as (
    select person, sum(amount) as subtotal
    from ex1 group by person
),
combined as (
    select person, food, amount from ex1
    union all
    select person, 'Subtotal' as food, subtotal as amount from subtotals
)
select * from combined order by person, food;
```

**Output**

```
  person  |   food   | amount
----------+----------+--------
 Joana    | Bananas  |      3
 Joana    | Juice    |      3
 Joana    | Orange   |      1
 Joana    | Subtotal |      7
 Jonathan | Bananas  |     10
 Jonathan | Orange   |      6
 Jonathan | Potato   |      2
 Jonathan | Subtotal |     18
 Luigi    | Orange   |     10
 Luigi    | Potato   |     10
 Luigi    | Subtotal |     20
 Mark     | Peanuts  |      7
 Mark     | Potato   |      5
 Mark     | Subtotal |     12
```

Hopefully that gets you what you want. This works as long as you don't have food alphabetically higher than Subtotal. If you do, you could change the query to use the word `ZZ-Subtotal-ZZ` or something like that to show up at the end of a person's food list.

Working example is here: https://rextester.com/VGO98471

Comment: I did something similar like you did, thanks it worked out. Sorry for the wait.